# Quadcopter controller program from smartphone

Tags: android, embedded, periodic-task

I'm developing an Android application to control my quadcopter from the smartphone: I have a periodic process that sends the data acquired from the touchscreen.
The data in then received from a microcontroller, that generates a PWM command to 4 DC motors, obtaining the duty cycle values with a control loop that exploits the received commands.

Can someone suggest a precise criterion to choose the period of the process on the smartphone? Or it is possibile only a "trial and error" approach, checking the reactivity of the system?

EDIT: I have successfully implemented it just setting the frequency of the smartphone task as 2*control_loop_frequency

Answer (score 0):

If you knew or could measure the impulse response of the system it would be possible to determine an appropriate control loop rate; however you do not have that data and it will be confounded in any case by external factors such as wind speed and direction.  Determining the rate empirically will be faster than determining the precise characteristics.

If the control is open-loop, then probably you have to ask yourself how far off the desired course can you allow the vehicle to get before a correction is applied.  That will depend on the vehicles maximum speed (in any direction).

In the end however Android is not a real-time operating system, so there are no guarantees that any particular periodic update will be performed precisely; its always going to be somewhat non deterministic.  At a guess I would imagine that such a system might manage 10Hz update reasonably reliably and that would probably be sufficient for adequate control and responsiveness - if the only feedback is via the human controller's hand-eye coordination, that is perhaps the limiting factor in the system response.